# Tasker: Variable with value "Name of Profile/Context"

Tags: automation, tasker, profiles, exchange-tasks

My Tasker version: `1.3.3u2m`; Android: `ICS 4.0.4`

To every Profile or Context I can set up Name. And I wanna use this Name with Tasks.

### Let's take an example:

1. I have Profile with Name "`SampleProf`"
2. In this Profile I have Context with name "`SampleCon`"
3. Next I wanna create Task like:

   - New Task > Variable > Variable Set

     - Name > Variable Select > `%sampleVar`
     - To > Variable Select > **HERE I WANT TO SELECT VARIABLE WITH NAME OF PROFILE("`SampleProf`") OR CONTECT("`SampleCon`")**

Is there way to do that at this moment?

I only see that there is "Profiles Active" variable (`%PACTIVE`), but, this puts as value, ALL names of Active Profiles.

Comment: for future ref, check https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/variables.html & https://grokbase.com/t/gg/tasker/14b74g9mh2/variable-with-name-of-current-profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option at this moment.

We can use "Profiles Active" variable (`%PACTIVE`).

Comment: And you can parse/split it, use a "like" compare, etc. It's a comma-separated list, so `~ *,myprof,*` or something alike should do.